# How understand $P\{(m+1) \mbox{st is a success, $k$ successes in first $m$ trials}\}$.

Tags: probability-theory

I wanna compute the conditional probability that the $(m+1)$st trial will result in a success given a total of $k$ success and $m-k$ failures in the first $m$ trials. Furthermore, the probability of successes is $p$, where $p$ is chosen by uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

So, my idea was 
$$P\{(m+1) \mbox{st trial is a success }\vert k \mbox{ successes in first m trials }\}$$
And by definition of conditional probability $P(A\vert B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, we have
$$=\dfrac{ P\{(m+1) \mbox{st is a success, $k$ successes in first $m$ trials}\} }{P\{ k \mbox{ successes in first $m$ trials} \}}$$

And I determine that, the denominator is $\dfrac{1}{m+1}$, but what happend with $P\{(m+1) \mbox{st is a success, $k$ successes in first $m$ trials}\}$? This is a binomial exp. Thanks!

Comment: The trials are independent?  Then the answer is $p$...doesn't matter what came before.

Comment: I thought something similar, but my teacher says that is $\int_{0}^{1}{P\{(m+1) \mbox{st is a success, $k$ in first $m$}\vert p \}dp}$. I think, because $p$ is chosen by uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, I should integrate on $(0,1)$, but is not clear the integral, thanks @lulu

Comment: Ok...maybe the issue is that $p$ is unknown?  That would make sense then.  a priori, you believed it was chosen uniformly but now you have $m$ observations so you don't think all $p$ are equally likely any more (e.g. if you have seen $5$ H in a row, it is unlikely that $p=.01$.  So then the problem is to estimate $p$.  Crude estimate is just $\frac km$ but you can do better .

Comment: This should be checked, but given that your prior was "uniform on $(0,1)$" and you observe $k$ hits out of $m$ then I believe your new estimate is $\frac {\int \binom mk p^{k}(1-p)^{m-k}pdp}{\int \binom mk p^{k}(1-p)^{m-k}dp}$.  (as I say, I think that's right but it's late and I might be being careless).

Comment: Sorry, maybe doesn't mentioned, but the idea of chosen $p$ by uniform distribution, is that $p$ now is a random variable, then I don't know what is  his value.

Comment: Oh right, my next step (if my teacher is right) is $\int_{0}^{1}{{m\choose k}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{m-k}dp}$ (as in your comment), but, what is the correct reason for the integral?

Comment: For each $p$ we compute the probability of seeing the given outcome, we then divide by the total probability that we saw that outcome to get the conditional probability. The result should be the best available estimate for $p$.  For example, if we toss once and get $H$ this would give $\frac {\int p^2 dp}{\int p dp}=\frac {\frac 13}{\frac 12}=\frac 23$ which seems sensible to me.

Comment: As I say though, I am quite tired and might well be making a blunder.  I'll revisit in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the the Comments:

The problem is asking this:  we are handed a coin and told that it will come up $H$ with some fixed probability $p$.  We are not given $p$ but we are assured that it is chosen uniformly on $(0,1)$.  We then toss the coin a number of times and seek to estimate $p$. Specifically, we toss it $m$ times and observe $k$ Heads.

We let $P(m,k,p)$ be the probability of observing $k$ Heads in $m$ throws, given that the probability is $p$. Of course we have $$P(m,k,p)=\binom mk p^k(1-p)^{m-k}$$
Suppose our prior was  the discrete case, with $p \in \{p_i\}_1^n$ each with probability $\frac 1n$.  then the probability that we observe the given outcome is $$\frac 1n \times \sum_i^nP(m,k,p_i)$$  Bayes tells us that our new estimate of $p$ is then $$\frac  {\frac 1n \times \sum_i^nP(m,k,p_i)\times p_i}{\frac 1n \times \sum_i^nP(m,k,p_i)}=\frac  {\sum_i^nP(m,k,p_i)\times p_i}{  \sum_i^nP(m,k,p_i)}$$

In our, continuous, case we get $$\Psi=\Psi(m,k)=\frac {\int_0^1P(m,k,p)pdp}{\int_0^1P(m,k,p)dp}=\frac {\int_0^1p^{k+1}(1-p)^{m-k}dp}{\int_0^1p^{k}(1-p)^{m-k}dp}$$  Of course these integrals are just values of the [Euler Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and we get:  $$\Psi=\frac {(k+1)!(m-k)!}{(m+2)!}\times \frac {(m+1)!}{(k)!(m-k)!}=\frac {k+1}{m+2}$$

Sanity check:  If you toss an even number of times, $m=2k$ and observe exactly $k$ Heads then the answer has to be $\frac 12$ by symmetry (as you also observed exactly $k$ Tails).  Here the integrals yield $\frac {k+1}{2k+2}=\frac 12$.

Comment: great answer and very clear, thanks!

Comment: And, also a comment, if $k=m$ (i.e., $k$  Heads in $m$ throws) this is a Laplace's Rule of sucession .